# How to write values to a csv file from another csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, export-to-csv, nested

For `index.csv` file, its fourth column has ten numbers ranging from `1`-`5`. Each number can be regarded as an index, and each index corresponds with an array of numbers in `filename.csv`.

The row number of `filename.csv` represents the index, and each row has three numbers. My question is about using a nesting loop to transfer the numbers in `filename.csv` to `index.csv`.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt  
import numpy as np  
import csv

data1 = genfromtxt('filename.csv', delimiter=',')  
data2 = genfromtxt('index.csv', delimiter=',')

f = open('index.csv','wb')  
write = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for row in data2:

    for ch_row in data1:

    if ( data2[row,3] == ch_row ):

    write.writerow(data1[data2[row,3],:])
```

For example, the fourth column of `index.csv` contains `1,2,5,3,4,1,4,5,2,3` and `filename.csv` contains:

```
# filename.csv

20 30 50 
70 60 45 
35 26 77 
93 37 68 
13 08 55
```

What I need is to write the indexed row from `filename.csv` to `index.csv` and store these number in 5th, 6th and 7th column:

```
# index.csv

#   4 5  6  7 
... 1 20 30 50 
... 2 70 60 45 
... 5 13 08 55 
... 3 35 26 77 
... 4 93 37 68 
... 1 20 30 50 
... 4 93 37 68 
... 5 13 08 55 
... 2 70 60 45 
... 3 35 26 77
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what the problem is with the code you have? How does what it produces differ from what you need?

Comment: For index.csv file, its fourth column has ten numbers ranging from 1~5. each number can be regarded as a index and each index corresponds with array of numbers in filename.csv. The row number of filename.csv represents the index and each row has three number. My question is using nesting loop to realize that transferring the number in filename.csv to index.csv

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do. My question is *what have **you** done to solve it so far*? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: I am trying to build a nesting loop to write the values to index.csv, but it doesn't work

Comment: Be more specific than *"it doesn't work"* - errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? As it stands, your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent your last 2 lines. Also, it looks like you are writing to the file from which you are reading.